# jQuery Validate plugin break my form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

[image]

I have an issue on my form with jQuery validate plugin, when I press save entry, it shows the error message but it breaks the form. How to fix this please?

At this time I have this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            loyalty_card: {
                required: true
            },
            description: {
                required: true
            },
            amount: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            transaction_type: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            //alert('valid form submitted');
            //return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That is an html structure issue, can you show your html for that relevant section?

Comment: Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/5prS9/

Comment: Hm, you don't have any of the defined `<span>` elements in there that I was expecting to see in order to adjust where the message shows. Perhaps there is a prepend option

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry but it's the first time I use this plugin.

Comment: Usually there is something along these lines: `<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="transaction_type" class="field-validation-valid"></span>`

Comment: Mmm ok. so do you suggest me to fix this by using a jquery css 'hack' for this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this by including the errorPlacement event hook, and then place the text before the radio button as opposed to directly after it

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element){
   if(  element.attr("name") == "transaction_type" ){
       error.insertBefore(element);
   }else{
       error.insertAfter(element);
   }
}
```